# Visual Studio Reference Project/Dll's

Tags: .net, winforms, visual-studio, architecture, reference

If i am having a list of projects in the order.

```
1. Commons
2. DAL
3. BAL
4. WebUI
```

In the above project the referencing should happen in this way.

```
DAL refer's to Commons.
BAL refer's to DAL.
WebUI refer's to BAL.
```

So, why it is giving an error when I am accessing a method of **BAL** from **WebUI** which returns an object which is defined in the **Commons**. As, in a project dependecies, WebUI depends on all three projects. But for the sake of easiness I don't want to include the reference of Common,BAL,DAL in the WebUI project. But what i want it should auto-include the reference of all the dependent project if any.

Can anyone help me out into this to how to get rid of this unexpected behavior of Visual Studio.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If `WebUI` uses *any* type that is defined in `Commons` then the `Commons` project **has to be** included as a reference to the `WebUI` project. Even if the type is used as a return type to a method that is declared in a different assembly (i.e. `BAL`) that the `WebUI` project is using.

There really is no way around this..

Comment: Don't you think, Visual Studio should automatically handle these kind of project reference hierarchy?

Comment: No. Not really.. because you might have a scenario where WebUI only uses some methods from let's say BAL that don't expose or work with any types defined in Commons. In that case you don't need a reference to Commons. So how would Visual Studio be able to make that determination for you?

Comment: thats very simple, because in any case the dll's which are being used by any referrencing project need to be copied. So why not referencing automatically?

Answer (score 1):

Referring to a DLL in a project doesn't include (copy) the DLL's code into the project. If `BAL` is returning objects defined in `Commons` to `WebUI`, then `WebUI` will need a reference to `Commons` as well so it knows about the types being returned.

If you want a way around this, you can try merging the assemblies together using [ILMerge](http://research.microsoft.com/en-us/people/mbarnett/ilmerge.aspx), and then reference the merged assemblies. I'd suggest doing this during software release. Otherwise, it seems it would make development and debugging more cumbersome.

Comment: Its a mess then, how come i can add 100's of project reference in each project within my solution if I make seperate dll's for every modules in my architecture.

Comment: @ManishRawat - unless you are building Office then having 100s of assemblies in your solution is likely overkill.. just a thought.

Comment: Although, when i see the bin/ folder of WebUI, then i can see all the dll's copied there. So it means Visual studio is automatically copying the dll's there, but not referencing them automatically.

Comment: It would seem unlikely that VS would copy the DLL if it wasn't being referenced. Maybe the files are leftovers from previous builds. Try recycling the bin folder and building again. See what ends up there.

Comment: It is indeed copying the dll's into the bin folder. See what i am saying is that, the WebUI referencing the BAL only, but still i found the DAL/Commons dll in the WebUI bin directory, this is because BAL has the dependency on DAL and DAL has the dependency on Commons. So, its automatically copied.

Comment: Then it's copied, not referenced. If WebUI can't find the types, then it is because there is no reference to the DLL. With no reference, the compiler doesn't know about it.

Comment: Its copied, what you mean here?